# Python - exchange server API get attendee availability

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I'm using python [exchangelib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exchangelib) - Client for Microsoft Exchange Web Services (EWS)

It's seems like this library did not implement the [GetUserAvailabilityRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564001(v=exchg.150).aspx) API.

I've searched all over the internet to see if someone implemented it, without any success.

Before I'm implement it by myself, maybe someone can help me to find a quick solution how to get the user availability calendar data.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the exchangelib author

If you do implement this within exchangelib, I'd love to pull it in.

In the meanwhile, I think your best be is to view the calendar of the user directly. It would require access to the user's calendar, of course. Something like this:

```
my_credentials = Credentials(...)
other_user = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='joebob@example.com',
    credentials=my_credentials, 
    autodiscover=True, 
    access_type=DELEGATE
)
for item in other_user.calendar.view(start=..., end=...):
    print(item.start, item.end, item.subject)
```